# Unable to download images from AWS S3, Swift 3

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, swift3

I have images uploaded to AWSS3 which I am trying to download using the below code.

The code does not run through `transferManager.download(downloadRequest).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.default(), block: { (task: AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in`, can someone please advice how I could fix this.

AWS SDK versions used (from pod file)
  `pod 'AWSCore', '~> 2.6.7'
  pod 'AWSS3', '~> 2.6.7'`

```
static func testDownload(){ 

    let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()

    let downloadingFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("temp.jpg")

    if let downloadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest(){

        downloadRequest.bucket = "bucket-name"
        downloadRequest.key = "folderName/imageName.png"
        downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL = downloadingFileURL
        print("downloadRequest \(downloadRequest)")
        transferManager.download(downloadRequest).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.default(), block: { (task: AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in

            print("transferManager.download func called")

            if( task.error != nil){
                print(task.error!.localizedDescription)
                return nil
            }

            print(task.result!)

            if let data = NSData(contentsOf: downloadingFileURL){

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    let image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
                    print("Downloaded Image: \(image)")
                })
            }
            return nil
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That block is a completion handler which would be called after the download has been completed. You can use the following code to track the progress of download as it happens:

```
downloadRequest.downloadProgress = {(bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64) -> Void in
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
        //Update progress
    })
}
```

Also, you can try using the main thread for testing purpose to see if it's something wrong with your bucket configuration or info.plist values or something else..

```
transferManager.download(downloadRequest).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread(), block: { (task:AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in

    if let error = task.error as? NSError {
        if error.domain == AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain, let code = AWSS3TransferManagerErrorType(rawValue: error.code) {
            switch code {
            case .cancelled, .paused:
                break
            default:
                print("Error downloading: \(downloadRequest.key) Error: \(error)")
            }
        } else {
            print("Error downloading: \(downloadRequest.key) Error: \(error)")
        }
        return nil
    }
    print("Download complete for: \(downloadRequest.key)")
    let downloadOutput = task.result
    return nil
})
```

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html

Comment: I realised that its taking 10x more time to download from S3 to iOS simulator, compared to downloading directly from a website to mac. I wonder why S3 is so slow.

Comment: btw, I find CloudFront CDN does the job pretty well at low cost